# Link Leaflet opacity slider to uppermost layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, transparency-opacity

From the Leaflet.OpacityControls plugin, you can add an opacity slider to a tiled layer by:

> var opacitySlider = new L.Control.opacitySlider();
>
> map.addControl(opacitySlider);
>
> opacitySlider.setOpacityLayer(interactive_layer);

I want the opacity slide-bar to link to not just one layer, but the tiled raster layer with the largest z-index (i.e. upper most layer) at any given time. How should I replace the `interactive_layer` var to do so?

Working with very limited JavaScript experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a suggested solution, may be not the best but it serves the purpose:

**HTML:** HTML slider control

```
<input id="slide" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1" onchange="updateOpacity(this.value)">
```

**Script:**  Update Opacity of top layer

```
function updateOpacity(value) {
    var interactive_layer = L.LayerGroup().getLayers()[0]; //In case you are using layer group. Also if you define the Layer group as Global variable, then you can call getLayers() directly.
    if(interactive_layer!=undefined)
       interactive_layer.setOpacity(value);
}
```

Comment: How would you write the `//Get top layer...` portion? That's the part I am missing. LayerGroup() is fine or any other function that achieves the same result.

Comment: What you are using in your code ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can use LayerGroup().getLayers()[0]

Comment: Nothing in particular, currently. I updated given your `L.LayerGroup().getLayers()[0];` and it works... but I want the `[0]` index to point to the layer in the LayerGroup with the largest z-index... in essence the top layer. Does that make sense?

Comment: try L.LayerGroup().getLayers()[L.LayerGroup().getLayers().length -1 ]

Comment: Doesn't quite work. I'm trying to enable layers with bootstrap checkboxes. So, have a base tiled layer with adjustable opacity, then select a checkbox for a overlaying tiled raster, and have that with adjustable opacity. The code you've given works for a single layer, but doesn't respond to the added layer.

Comment: You have one adjustable opacity only that you want to use with any upper overlay layer ??

Comment: That's correct. One control function, but that simply applies to the upper most overlay layer. Basically applying it to the overlay layer with the highest z-index.

Comment: Well, when you are adding checkboxes for each layer, get layer ID and set to checkbox like <input type=checkbox data-layerid='[layerid]' class=overlayLayers />  but don't do that to base layer. Then on 'change' event of slider get the checked checboxes and pick the top one then get the layer ID value and use it to fetch layer from LayerGroup() function.

Comment: Awesome. Found the place in my code to add the line. Thanks very much. I'm adjusting code, so had a lot to work off but am unfamiliar with JS.

Comment: I advise you to learn it, it is more than important.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called Leaflet.Control.Opacity.

https://github.com/dayjournal/Leaflet.Control.Opacity

Comment: Could you try expand on this answer? Just in case in future the link you have suggested is no longer in use.

Comment: This is listed at https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html. Also check out https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=leaflet